# Porting Solar Wind XNA example to Helix 3d WPF

Tags: wpf, 3d, xna, silverlight-5.0, helix-3d-toolkit

I am looking to port the Silverlight 5 / XNA example Solar Wind to WPF using the Helix3d toolkit.

The Solar Wind example is here:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Solar-Wind-3D-Sample-4cb56170

I watched the video demonstrating the example and one of the great features is that the 3d geometry is expressed as XML and can be changed at runtime.  This makes it possible for example to change terrain height or color at runtime based on sets of data.

I have been looking at the Helix 3d toolkit which looks amazing.

It can be found at:

http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/

I am aware that 3d geometry can be expressed as XAML in the Helix 3d toolkit.  Is it possible to change the Geometry dynamically at runtime to support similar behaviour as the Solar Wind example does in XNA?

Comment: You should probably explore other 3D engines and toolkits, maybe you can find something that better fits your needs, but first you should find out what you really need. For example, Unity3d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user1306322 that just looks like a plug for Unity3d.  Unity is a great engine, but I was suggested Helix 3d because it is built to integrate with WPF applications.

A beter suggestion in terms of porting the Solar Winds example would actually be Monogame, because it fully (well almost) supports the XNA framework, but supports DirectX 11 and multi platforms.